# Problems generating #FNI programming barcode on screen in Android

Tags: socketscan

I want to generate a Bluetooth initator command barcode in the following format (#FNIaabbccddeeff#) on screen in Android, to automate the paring process.

I'm using zxing library to generate this in Code128 format. The scanner refuses to understand the barcode. But any softscan application on android easily understand the barcode. If I generate a code with barcode.tec-it.com on the PC screen the scanner detect immediately.

In the Socketscan application on google play the same barcode is displayed and the scanner decodes correctly.

The scanner is a Socket Mobile CHS 7ci scanner.

Any idea?

Edit: Solved, I had managed to get a leading space in before the hash tag when building the barcode.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?